# ¿Cómo puedo hacer un import de una función para redux-form?

Tags: reactjs, redux

Tengo una clase que usa el formulario de redux-form y en mi función `render()` llamo esto:

```
<Field
    name="type"
    label = "Type Device"
    component={this.renderSelect}>
        <option></option>
        <option name="ios">iOS</option>
        <option name="android">Android</option>
</Field>
```

La función que se llama en `component` la tengo en el misma clase:

```
renderInput(field) {
    return(
        <div>
            <label>{field.label}</label>
            <input
                type={field.type}
                placeholder={field.placeholder}
                {...field.input}
            />
            {field.meta.touched && field.meta.error && <span>{field.meta.error}</span>}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Quiero dejarla como función en otro archivo así `import renderInput  from './form.js';` luego la imprimo así `console.log(this.renderInput);` pero me lanza `undefined`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo hice así:

```
function mapStateToProps(state, props) {
    return {
        renderInput: renderInput
    }
}
```

Y en mi clase lo puedo ocupar así `this.props.renderField`